# Java/Fortify - Unreleased resource:Stream

Tags: java, fortify, try-with-resources

```
try (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream out = (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream) this.httpConnect.getOutputStream();) {
```

For this line fortify is giving - Unreleased resource:Stream Vulnerability. Any reason? We have already added it into try with resorces.

Do I need to use the old pattern [try.catch/finally] to close the resource?

Here, `this.httpConnect` is : `HttpURLConnection httpConnect = null;`

Please provide some suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably if `getOutputStream()` returns something other than a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (or `null`) then the cast will throw. The resource will not reach the `try` so cannot be closed.

So, avoid doing the cast in the try-with-resource statement expression. Or preferably, avoid casts altogether.